# Printing one sentence per line after a for loop

Tags: python

I have a text file and I want to 1) iterate over each of its sentences, then 2) over each word of its sentences to modify some of them and then 3) print the resulting new version of the text one sentence per line

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import my_text

for sentence in my_text.sents():
    for word in sentence:
        if word == "the":
            print("article", end= " ")
        else:
            print("non-article", end= " ")
     if word == sentence[-1]:
        print("\n")
```

This code works and my text is modified and printed one sentence per line. However, there's an empty line between each sentence, and I'd like to remove that. Example:

```
article non-article non-article non-article

non-article non-article non-article non-article non-article non-article

article non-article non-article non-article
```

And this is what I want:

```
article non-article non-article non-article
non-article non-article non-article non-article non-article non-article
article non-article non-article non-article
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `print("\n")`, the default value of end is `"\n"` so each time you `print("\n")` it prints `"\n\n"`. Just use `print()`:

```
sentences = ["the cat and dog", "the mouse and cat", "the fox and else"]
sentences = [sentence for sentence in map(str.split, sentences)]

for sentence in sentences:
    for word in sentence:
        if word == "the":
            print("article", end=" ")
        else:
            print("non-article", end=" ")

        if word == sentence[-1]:
            print()
```

**Output**

```
article non-article non-article non-article 
article non-article non-article non-article 
article non-article non-article non-article
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
import my_text

for sentence in my_text.sents():
  end = " "
  for word in sentence:
    if word == sentence[-1]:
        end = "\n"
    if word == "the":
        print("article", end=end)
    else:
        print("non-article", end=end)
```